# Extend(wide) or Narrow titles by listing them in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table in SSRS 2008 like:

```
Zone    NumOfPeople
Zone1     50
Zone2     30
Zone3     20
```

What I want is to change the table into:

```
     Zone   NumOfPeople
+  AllZones    100
```

When I click `+` sign, I expect to see something like:

```
   Zone            NumOfPeople
- AllZones   Zone1     50
             Zone2     30
             Zone3     20
```

And clicking `-` sign should return the table to its first display. So I want to wide or narrow a table by clicking +/- like that. I could not find a related page that tells how to do it. I appreciate if anyone helps me to understand. Thanks!!

Edit1: 
SQL Query for the table in SSRS:

```
Select Zone, Count(distinct Person_Id) as NumOfPeople
From myTable
group by Zone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty examples in the web for toggling expand/collapse actions in SSRS. For your requeriment is necessary to create an additional column that you can cast in the query or hardcode it in the tablix textbox.

My apprach generates the `All Zones` group from the query and names the column as `All`.

```
Select 'All Zones' [All],Zone, Count(distinct Person_Id) as NumOfPeople
From myTable
group by Zone
```

Add a tablix with the following data arrangement.

[image]

In `Row Groups` right click on the `Zone` subgroup (All child group) and select the `Group Properties...` in the `Visibility` tab set the following settings.

[image]

Select the correct `All` toggle item, in my case is `All1`

It will preview the following:

[image]

Let me know if this helps you.