# Extend/collapse a matrix in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on Microsoft Reporting Services 2008. There is a table I have like:

```
Name   Point
Alice  60
Mike   40
```

I want to arrange an extend/collapse on this table to make it like:

```
Name   Point
+Total  100
```

When I click +, I expect to see:

```
Name   Point
-Total  100
Alice   60
Mike    40
```

And clicking - will do the reverse. I see the post [Extend(wide) or Narrow titles by listing them in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799223/extendwide-or-narrow-titles-by-listing-them-in-ssrs-2008), it is so close to my question but it does not work for my situation since I cannot choose [Name] when I go to Name group and go visibility section as described there. I also do NOT want Total in another column like below:

```
-Total   Alice  60
         Mike   40
```

I couldnt solve it on my own. If someone helps I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a group to set toggle functionality it can be used on any cell of your tablix.

Create a tablix with the following data arrangement.

[image]

Total is hardcoded, drag and drop the Name and Point fields to the cells on the details group.

Select the row and right click it, select `Row Visibility...` :

[image]

In the Row Visibility window select Hide and Display can be toggled by this report item: choose the textbox where Total was hardcoded.

[image]

In my case is Textbox 71.

Now preview your report, you will get something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, thanks for your answer. I couldnt clearly understand where textbox71 is in ur case. I appreciate if you show it as well.

Comment: @EmelUras , Oh I passed over the fact it can be tricky. In SSRS every tablix cell has a name, if the cell is hardcoded or set to an expression the textbox name will be textbox #. To know the textbox name just select the cell and press F4, a properties windows will be show. Also if you right click the cell and select textbox properties you will see the Name property. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @EmelUras, Textbox71 is the name of the cell where Total is hardcoded i.e the cell we want to create the toggle `[+]` functionality.